# How to call super.setText inside nested onClick on extended EditText?

Tags: java, android

I want to create custom editText when you click on editText it will automatically insert a defined text. So I create custom editText that extends editText and implements View.onClickListeners. But calling super.setText inside the onClick method doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code of the custom editText

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context context;
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        super.setText("MY TEXT HERE");
    }
}
```

So on MainActivity onCreate I will only need to declare and set the listener

```java
        CustomEditText myText = new CustomEditText(this);
        myText.setOnClickListener(new CustomEditText(this));
        linearLayout.addView(myText);
```

if I put the super.setText inside the constructor, it fills the custom Edit Text. But if I put it on OnClick, it didn't fill my custom Edit Text eventhough it does call the super.setText inside OnClick (when debugging)

The purpose of this is I want to create custom editText later on that show datePicker and enter the date when the date is chosen. Everything should be done on custom editText class so the main Activity is only for object declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `clicked` view to set the text.

Try this inside your `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ((EditText)view).setText("MY TEXT HERE");
}
```